# Forming combinations of a 16 bit binary number

Tags: java, performance, recursion

I wrote this code to form combinations of a 16 bit binary number (I know it is in output is string format, but it is my goal to just print all possible 16 bit binary numbers). My question is, can this code be optimized? How can I calculate the time complexity of this code?

```
public class Combinations {

    static int len;

    public static void formCombinations(StringBuilder start,String[] possible)
    {
        if(start.length()==len)
        {
            System.out.println(start);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<possible.length;i++)
        {   
            formCombinations(start.append(possible[i]), possible);
            start.deleteCharAt(start.length()-1);
        }
    }

    public static void formCombinations(int len,String[] a) {
        Combinations.len=len;
        formCombinations(new StringBuilder(""), a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[]={"0","1"};
        formCombinations(16, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `new StringBuilder("")` to `new StringBuilder()`

Comment: @SteveKuo why, can you please explain? what is the difference between those two?

Comment: Is this [tag:java]? Please tag your question with a language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Give your operators some breathing space, e.g.:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < possible.length; i++)
  ```
- `possible` is not very good name (it implies that something is `impossible`. I recommend `alphabet` instead.
- `possible` never changes. It makes it a good candidate for a final class member. Passing it down recursively wastes some stack space.
- I don't think overloading `formCombinations` is warranted.
- I see nothing obviously wrong performance wise. After all, you generate *all* permutations, and you generate each permutation exactly once. Of course, `StringBuilder` may impose some hidden penalties; Java experts would give an authoritative answer.

  In any case, an iterative solution requires less space, doesn't need a `StringBuilder`, and may serve as an iterator (in a sense of supporting `has_next()` and `next()` methods). I highly recommend implementing it: it is simple and instructive. Hint: think of next permutation as adding 1 to a binary number.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void formCombinations(int len , String[] a){
     //calculate the number of possible combinations
     int totalRepeats = Math.pow(a.length , len);
     //list of indices from which the resulting strings will be built
     int[] path = new int[len];

     boolean increaseNext;

     //the array of currently used elements (intially populated)
     String[] curString = new String[len];
     for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
          curString[i] = a[i];

     //the index of the highest increased element (lowest index)
     int highestIncreased;

     for(int i = 0 ; i < totalRepeats ; i++){
         //calculate the next combination of elements
         increaseNext = true;
         for(highestIncreased = len - 1 ; increaseNext ; highestIncreased--){
              ++path[j];
              if(increaseNext = (path[j] == len))
                   path[j] = 0;
         }

          //update the string
          for(; highestIncreased < len ; highestIncreased++)
               curString[highestIncreased] = a[path[highestIncreased]];

          //print the string (might be optimized aswell)
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(curString));
     }
}
```

Since your code is recursive, you need `a.length ^ len` method calls. method calls are quite resource intensive. So this should actually run faster. calculating time complexity is a bit too complicated to explain it here. and time complexity is usually only calculated for algorithms with input.

NOTE: i haven't tested this code, so it might be buggy. but it should show how it basically works.

Comment: actually, its not causing stack overflow, and it is working perfectly. What if I want to form combinations of array {"a","b","c","d","e"}, the method you said will only generate binary numbers.

Comment: if you want characters, simply replace `Integer.toBinaryString((short) i)` with `(char) i`. for the stack overflow, my bad, i misunderstood the code

Comment: sorry that my question is misleading. But I want to form combinations of 16 letter word that can be formed using 5 letters {"a","b","c","d","e"}.

Comment: ok, now i get it, there are still ways to optimize this. ill edit to post to match the actual requirements